# In React Native, I want to Add Dynamic Drawer Navigation Item which data come from api(fetch)

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, dynamic-programming, es6-promise

Here is my Static code:

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <MyApp />
    )
  }
}

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (

  <View style={{position:'relative', height:'100%'}}>
    <View style={styles.drawerHeader}>
        <ImageBackground style={styles.back} source={require('./src/Header/banner.jpg')}>
          <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Image
              style={styles.drawerImage}
              source={require('./src/shirsho.png')} />
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
    </View>
    <View>
      {/* <DrawerItems {...props} /> */}
      <DrawerItems {...props}  
        activeTintColor='#000' 
        activeBackgroundColor='#e3e3e3' 
        inactiveTintColor='rgba(0, 0, 0, .87)' 
        inactiveBackgroundColor='transparent' 
        itemsContainerStyle= {{ marginTop: 0,}}
        itemStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 2, borderBottomColor: '#eee',}} 
        labelStyle={{fontSize: 16,color: '#000'}}/>
    </View>
    <View style={{width:100,height:50, position:'absolute', bottom:0,right:30}}>
          <Image
              style={{width:100, marginLeft: 10,}}
              source={require('./src/bdtask.png')} />
    </View>

  </View>

);

const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
  'হোম' : {
    screen : Homepage,
  },
  'জাতীয়' :{
    screen : NationalTab,
  },
  'খেলা' :{
    screen : PlayTab,
  },
  'প্রশাসন' :{
    screen : AdminTab,
  },
  'অর্থনীতি' :{
    screen : EconomicsTab,
  },
  'বিনোদন' :{
    screen : EntertainmentTab,
  },
  'শিক্ষা' :{
    screen : EducationTab,
  }
},{
  initialRouteName: 'হোম',
  drawerPosition: 'left',
  contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
})


export default App
```

Also, I want to pass value as props with this drawer item.

Comment: Here is the screenshot
https://prnt.sc/l4z73o
https://prnt.sc/l4z7bs